# loading with simple opengl image library(SOIL) an image(color space: GRAY)

Tags: c++, image, png, soil

I want to read out the pixel values of an grey scale image. With RGB images I have no problems. The code is just simply:

```
int width, height;
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(filepath.c_str(), &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
std::cout << "size of image : " << size  << " width: " << width << " height: " << height << std::endl;
```

Now I want to load an image(png) with color space GRAY, I thought I could simply change SOIL_LOAD_RGB to SOIL_LOAD_L but that don't work out.

My output on the console is:
size of image : -237407992 width: 10 height: -1312230988

And it is not constant. Only the width stays 10, and the height is changing every time I run the program.

Is there something I have to change or consider when working with gray scale images?

Comment: language is c++. I added a tag

Answer (score 0):

You should change the third parameter from '0' to '&channel', like this

```
unsigned char *image = SOIL_load_image(filepath.c_str(), &width, &height, &channel, SOIL_LOAD_L);
```